# InvalidResourceException : property RestApiID not defined for resource of type Api

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am getting an error Error:

```
[InvalidResourceException('APIFunctionpersonapi', 'property RestApiID not defined for resource of type Api')] ('APIFunctionpersonapi', 'property RestApiID not defined for resource of type Api')
```

```
Resources:
  APIFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: APIFunction
      Handler: com.java.Handler::handleRequest
      Policies:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecretsManagerReadWrite
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 1024
      Environment: 
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        personapi:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /myapi/person
            Method: post
            RestApiID: !Ref SamTestPrivateApi
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: 
        SubnetIds: 
   SamTestPrivateApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      OpenApiVersion: 3.0.3
      StageName: !Ref Environment
```

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidResourceException : property RestApiID not defined for resource of type Api

Check the [SAM cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli) release notes and updated to the latest version. Then try again.

Comment: What does this mean? Release notes for what version?

Comment: @JonMadison You can try using the latest version, but if it does not work, try the corresponding version by matching the answer date on https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases.